# What happens if I have a weekly log rotate configuration and I reboot my device every other day?

Tags: bash, logrotate

I have a weekly log rotate configuration, but my device is never powered on longer than a week. Does it ever perform log rotation? Or does the device need to be powered more than a week to trigger the rotation?

```
/path/to/my/log.log
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    maxsize 150M
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat Linux and family, and Debian GNU/Linux and family usually have anacron installed.

Anacron will be executed each time your computer is booted, and it will check the last date the cron was running. If the last date is more than 7 days since today, the scripts in /etc/cron.weekly will be run.

If logrotate is inside /etc/cron.weekly, then it will be run by cron